# multiple level Data frame

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I am looking on how to store multiple instances of different variables types in R. I tried to use dataframes (and lists) but cannot get it to do what I want. Let me try to show you with an example what I would like to achieve.

Let's say I create a type of data type (a basket) that contains a number and a string, like :

```
iNbLine = 2
df<-data.frame(Weight=double(iNbLine), Color=character(iNbLine),stringsAsFactors=F)
row.names(df)<-c("apples","pears")
df
       Weight Color
apples      0      
pears       0
```

I can now update my data structure as I want. For example :

```
df$Weight[1]=158
df$Color[1]="green"
df
       Weight Color
apples    158 green
pears       0
```

What I would like to do however is have a higher-level data than contains several of these baskets with additional data(here the price), so I tried this :

```
iNbBasket =5
df2<-data.frame(Price=double(iNbBasket), Basket=rep(df,iNbBasket))
```

But this gives me

```
Error in data.frame(Price = double(iNbBasket), Basket = rep(df, iNbBasket)) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 2
```

What I would like to be able to do is access the weight of apples of my 2nd basket for example; while keeping the possibility to set the price of the 2nd basket. I hope this is clear enough. In C language, I think I was able to define a new data type (basket) using "struct", which I could then include in another data type but I cannot figure how to do it here.

For @joran this is an attempt to show what I would like :

```
                       Baskets      
Name    Price   Names   Weight  Color
Basket1 250     apples  158     green
                pears   32      yellow
Basket2 120     apples  70      green
                pears   10      yellow
```

But being able to access line 3, by something like :

```
myBasket<-myData[2]
myBasket$Weight[1]
70
```

and do :

```
myBasket$Price = 130
```

**Update 1**
I looked through lists, S3 variable types, and dplyr. I have to admit I did not understand everything but so far I do not have exactly what I want. I currently do the following

```
iNbLine = 2
df<-data.frame(Weight=double(iNbLine), Color=c("green","yellow"),stringsAsFactors=F)
row.names(df)<-c("apples","pears")

iNbBasket=3
dfBaskets<-data.frame(Price=double(iNbBasket))
row.names(dfBaskets)=c("Basket1","Basket2","Basket3")

lBasketsContent<-list()
for(i in 1:iNbBasket){
    lBasketsContent[[i]]=df
}
```

This way I can access the price :

```
iBasket =2
dfBaskets$Price[2] = 150
```

and any element of a given basket :

```
lBasketsContent[[2]]$Weight[1] = 300
```

as well as the basket itself (I pass it to a function in my real case)

```
dfBasket<-lBasketsContent[[2]]
```

It is easy to read but requires 2 containers.

Comment: Generally, a data frame can be represented as a single rectangular grid of data elements (i.e. think a spreadsheet). Can you edit your question to include what that rectangular grid should look like for your desired output?

Comment: Look at S3 and S4 objects, or look at creating a multidimensional matrix

Comment: @joran, OK then a data frame is not what I want as I need multiple levels of data

Comment: I'm not 100% convinced a data frame couldn't hold the data you describe, but if you're looking for more general "objects" as you might find in other programming languages I would _not_ consider S3, but I would look at S4, Reference Classes or R6 (which is a package).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hadley's [`tidyr`](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr) (with [`purrr`](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/)) provide something like this. Take a look at ["tidyr 0.4.0"](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/02/02/tidyr-0-4-0/) for a demonstration of complex structures nested within a data.frame cell.

Their examples typically rely on having relevant information in the other cells *before* populated the others, and even then populating them based on some form of grouping. For example, using `mtcars`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>%
  transmute(model = rownames(mtcars), mpg, cyl, disp, gear) %>%
  group_by(cyl)
# Source: local data frame [32 x 5]
# Groups: cyl [3]
#                model   mpg   cyl  disp  gear
#                <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1          Mazda RX4  21.0     6 160.0     4
# 2      Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0     6 160.0     4
# 3         Datsun 710  22.8     4 108.0     4
# 4     Hornet 4 Drive  21.4     6 258.0     3
# 5  Hornet Sportabout  18.7     8 360.0     3
# 6            Valiant  18.1     6 225.0     3
# 7         Duster 360  14.3     8 360.0     3
# 8          Merc 240D  24.4     4 146.7     4
# 9           Merc 230  22.8     4 140.8     4
# 10          Merc 280  19.2     6 167.6     4
# # ... with 22 more rows
```

If we call `nest()` on a grouping, you can see how things are compacted a bit:

```
quux1 <- mtcars %>%
  transmute(model = rownames(mtcars), mpg, cyl, disp, gear) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest()
quux1
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#     cyl              data
#   <dbl>            <list>
# 1     6  <tibble [7 x 4]>
# 2     4 <tibble [11 x 4]>
# 3     8 <tibble [14 x 4]>
quux1$data[[1]]
# # A tibble: 7 x 4
#            model   mpg  disp  gear
#            <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1      Mazda RX4  21.0 160.0     4
# 2  Mazda RX4 Wag  21.0 160.0     4
# 3 Hornet 4 Drive  21.4 258.0     3
# 4        Valiant  18.1 225.0     3
# 5       Merc 280  19.2 167.6     4
# 6      Merc 280C  17.8 167.6     4
# 7   Ferrari Dino  19.7 145.0     5
```

You can do some processing on this, `dplyr`-style:

```
quux2 <- mtcars %>%
  transmute(model = rownames(mtcars), mpg, cyl, disp, gear) %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(mpg2 = purrr::map(data, ~ lm(mpg ~ disp + gear, data = .)))
quux2
# # A tibble: 3 x 3
#     cyl              data     mpg2
#   <dbl>            <list>   <list>
# 1     6  <tibble [7 x 4]> <S3: lm>
# 2     4 <tibble [11 x 4]> <S3: lm>
# 3     8 <tibble [14 x 4]> <S3: lm>
```

And deal with the models individually:

```
summary(quux2$mpg2[[2]])
# Call:
# lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + gear, data = .)
# Residuals:
#     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -3.2691 -1.7130  0.0708  1.7617  3.4351 
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# (Intercept) 30.77234    7.33123   4.197  0.00301 **
# disp        -0.13189    0.03094  -4.263  0.00275 **
# gear         2.38529    1.54132   1.548  0.16032   
# ---
# Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
# Residual standard error: 2.623 on 8 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.7294,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.6618 
# F-statistic: 10.78 on 2 and 8 DF,  p-value: 0.005361
```

A more robust use of this would deal with the models programmatically, of course, but this is just a start.

*NB: I am not suggesting that `mpg ~ disp + gear` is a reasonable model :-)*

**Update 1**

How about this:

Start with "default" basket contents, a hybrid list/data.frame:

```
df <- list(Price = 0,
           Contents = data.frame(Names = c("apples", "pears"),
                                 Weight = rep(0, 2L),
                                 Color = c("green","yellow"),
                                 stringsAsFactors = F)
           )
```

Create a list of three baskets (three customers?):

```
nBaskets <- 3L
# start with 3 empty baskets
lBaskets <- replicate(nBaskets, df, simplify = FALSE)
str(lBaskets)
# List of 3
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ Price   : num 0
#   ..$ Contents:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. ..$ Names : chr [1:2] "apples" "pears"
#   .. ..$ Weight: num [1:2] 0 0
#   .. ..$ Color : chr [1:2] "green" "yellow"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ Price   : num 0
#   ..$ Contents:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. ..$ Names : chr [1:2] "apples" "pears"
#   .. ..$ Weight: num [1:2] 0 0
#   .. ..$ Color : chr [1:2] "green" "yellow"
#  $ :List of 2
#   ..$ Price   : num 0
#   ..$ Contents:'data.frame':  2 obs. of  3 variables:
#   .. ..$ Names : chr [1:2] "apples" "pears"
#   .. ..$ Weight: num [1:2] 0 0
#   .. ..$ Color : chr [1:2] "green" "yellow"
```

Now, customer 2 wants to buy something:

```
cust <- 2
lBaskets[[ cust ]]$Contents$Weight[1] <- 300
lBaskets[[ cust ]]$Price <- 150
lBaskets[[ cust ]]
# $Price
# [1] 150
# $Contents
#    Names Weight  Color
# 1 apples    300  green
# 2  pears      0 yellow
```

Without getting into S4 objects (perhaps over-engineered for what you are trying to do), I think this is the most straight-forward way. If you want/need to make a quick reference to a specific customer's `Contents` and reassign it back into the list, that's certainly doable but not required.

Comment: You asked for multiple levels in data.frames. That's what this may give you, albeit in a different perspective. Did I misinterpret when you suggested you wanted a whole data.frame embedded within a cell of another data.frame?

Comment: Oh, I think I see, you aren't interested necessarily in the *processing* of nested data.frames, just the presentation where the grouping variables on the left are not repeated. That is, you really don't need it embedded, just pretty-printed. Is that right?

Comment: No, I need to be able to access all elements in a logical way. This is about the only "processing" I would do though

Comment: Using my examples (the first nesting), does it make sense to access `quux1$data[[1]]$mpg` to get the `mpg` values associated with `quux1$cyl[1]`? (More generically, `quux1$data[[k]]` contains all the data associated with `quux1$cyl[k]`.)

Comment: kind of , but I really to struggle to link it to what I want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121576/discussion-between-r2evans-and-djiggy).

Comment: Thanks, but sorry, I cannot access the chat part of the website through my firewall

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted I think, well done. I still do not understand what you did different from my attempt number 284, but it works ! Thanks. I ll try and implement it in my real world case and see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Use `lists`. Lists are generic vectors able to contain other objects

- [Link 1](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Lists)
- [Link 2](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/list)

Using a `data.table` for example:

```
> library(data.table)
> baskets = data.table( 
    'name'=c('basket1','basket2'),
    'price'=c(250,120),
    'names'=list( list('apples','pears') , list('apples','pears') ),
    'weight'=list( list(158,32) , list(70,10) ),
    'color'=list( list('green','yellow') , list('green','yellow'))
)

> baskets
      name price  names weight  color
1: basket1   250 <list> <list> <list>
2: basket2   120 <list> <list> <list>
>
```

Grabbing the first row information

```
> baskets[1][['price']]
[1] 250
> baskets[1][['names']][[1]][[2]]
[1] "pears"
> baskets[1][['weight']][[1]][[2]]
[1] 32
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I need to be able to extract each "basket" as a variable I can pass to another function easily. My current best solution is to have one data frame containing the basket names and price on one side and a list of same dimension containing all my baskets on the other side. This is not nice but does the job until I find better.

Answer (score 0):

We need to convert the first data.frame to matrix and use `byrow=TRUE`

```
iNbLine = 2
DF<-data.frame(Weight=double(iNbLine), Color=character(iNbLine),stringsAsFactors=F)
row.names(DF)<-c("apples","pears")
DF

DF$Weight[1]=158
DF$Color[1]="green"
DF$Weight[2]=200
DF$Color[2]="red"


iNbBasket =5
DF_MultiLevel<-data.frame(Price=double(iNbBasket), Basket= matrix(rep(DF,iNbBasket),nrow=iNbBasket,byrow=TRUE) )

#> DF_MultiLevel
#  Price Basket.1   Basket.2
#1     0 158, 200 green, red
#2     0 158, 200 green, red
#3     0 158, 200 green, red
#4     0 158, 200 green, red
#5     0 158, 200 green, red
```

Comment: Not sure it works, Basket1 contains all Weights and Basker2 contains all colours

Comment: This is necessary because @Osssan chose to use `array`s (`matrix` is a special-case array). In an `array`, all values must be of the same type, up-converting (`integer` < `numeric` < `character`) if mixed-class.